# How can I make my hashmap public to be printed from anywhere in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to be able to print a hashmap inside a threaded method, but I can't figure out how to make it global or how to pass the hashmap as a parameter to the function. Could someone help me with this please?
I think my problem is that, maybe, I am doing everything from one file? Is it possible to do what I need from one file like this?

Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Thread;

public class Server{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){

    if (args.length < 1) return;

    HashMap<String, String> Distances = new HashMap<String, String>(); // here's the map
    
    menu mThread = new menu();

    try{ 
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    Distances.put(ip.toString(), "0");
    System.out.println(Distances);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    
    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
    
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
        System.out.println("server is listening on port " + port);

        while(true){
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected");      
        serverSocket.close();
        System.exit(0);
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("exception");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
class menu implements Runnable{
    menu(){
    Thread m = new Thread(this);
    m.run();
    }
    public void run(){
    printMenu();
    }
    public void printMenu(){
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice;
    System.out.println("1. help\n 2. routing\n 3. myPort");
    while(choice != 4){
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1)
        System.out.println("control c to quit, otherwise make another selection");
        else if (choice == 2)
        System.out.println(Distances); // here is the issue

    }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code isn't indented properly and doesn't follow Java naming conventions. You should program to the interface (Map or ConcurrentMap), not the implementation, and use the diamond syntax so you don't have to repeat the types of the map.

Comment: I'm going to be honest and admit I don't really understand what you mean. This is my first time coding in java. I came from the C world.

Comment: You would create a HashMap like `Map<String, String> distances = new HashMap<>();` There's no need to repeat the types inside the angle brackets; the compiler can infer them. On the left hand side, you use the interface `Map` so that if later you switch from a `HashMap` to a `ConcurrentHashMap` you don't have to change that. In Java, class names (`Menu`) and other user-defined types begin with an uppercase letter, while methods and variables (`distances`) begin with lowercase letters. Not enforced by the compiler, but helpful to your fellow programmers when reading your code.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should know that HashMap isn't thread safe, so it would be better to use ConcurentHashMap. One of the way to implement desired behaviour is to create a class that would accept a map as constructor parameter, so you will be able to pass it and use it a run method. Then you have to pass instance of the class to the Thread. Here's a really simple example - https://intellipaat.com/community/24428/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-java-thread.